# TCP handshake fails

Tags: tcp, gridgain

I'm trying to connect 500 nodes on gridgain 2.1.1. and Windows Server 2008 R2 standard, but the topology recognizes only 100 nodes or so with the following errors. Any suggestions?

```
13/04/16 19:01:01.472 [INFO ] [main] [***GridTcpCommunicationSpi] Failed to bind to local port (will try next port within range) [port=20000, localHost=***calc007/10.***.19.77]
13/04/16 19:01:01.472 [INFO ] [main] [***GridTcpCommunicationSpi] Failed to bind to local port (will try next port within range) [port=20001, localHost=***calc007/10.***.19.77]
13/04/16 19:01:01.472 [INFO ] [main] [***GridTcpCommunicationSpi] Failed to bind to local port (will try next port within range) [port=20002, localHost=***calc007/10.***.19.77]
13/04/16 19:01:01.472 [INFO ] [main] [***GridTcpCommunicationSpi] Failed to bind to local port (will try next port within range) [port=20003, localHost=***calc007/10.***.19.77]
13/04/16 19:01:01.472 [INFO ] [main] [***GridTcpCommunicationSpi] Failed to bind to local port (will try next port within range) [port=20004, localHost=***calc007/10.***.19.77]
13/04/16 19:01:01.472 [INFO ] [main] [***GridTcpCommunicationSpi] Failed to bind to local port (will try next port within range) [port=20005, localHost=***calc007/10.***.19.77]
13/04/16 19:01:01.472 [INFO ] [main] [***GridTcpCommunicationSpi] Failed to bind to local port (will try next port within range) [port=20006, localHost=***calc007/10.***.19.77]
13/04/16 19:01:01.472 [INFO ] [main] [***GridTcpCommunicationSpi] Failed to bind to local port (will try next port within range) [port=20007, localHost=***calc007/10.***.19.77]
13/04/16 19:01:01.472 [INFO ] [main] [***GridTcpCommunicationSpi] Failed to bind to local port (will try next port within range) [port=20008, localHost=***calc007/10.***.19.77]
13/04/16 19:01:01.472 [INFO ] [main] [***GridTcpCommunicationSpi] Successfully bound to TCP port: 20009
13/04/16 19:01:01.472 [INFO ] [main] [***GridTcpCommunicationSpi] Using parameter [localAddr=null]
13/04/16 19:01:01.472 [INFO ] [main] [***GridTcpCommunicationSpi] Using parameter [msgThreads=5]
13/04/16 19:01:01.472 [INFO ] [main] [***GridTcpCommunicationSpi] Using parameter [localPort=20000]
13/04/16 19:01:01.472 [INFO ] [main] [***GridTcpCommunicationSpi] Using parameter [localPortRange=9999]
13/04/16 19:01:01.472 [INFO ] [main] [***GridTcpCommunicationSpi] Using parameter [idleConnTimeout=30000]
13/04/16 19:01:01.472 [INFO ] [main] [***GridTcpCommunicationSpi] Using parameter [directBuf=true]
13/04/16 19:01:01.487 [INFO ] [main] [***GridTcpCommunicationSpi] SPI started ok [startMs=15, spiMBean=org.gridgain:group=SPIs,name=***GridTcpCommunicationSpi]
13/04/16 19:01:01.597 [INFO ] [main] [***GridMulticastDiscoverySpi] Using parameter [mcastGroup=239.***.201.1]
13/04/16 19:01:01.597 [INFO ] [main] [***GridMulticastDiscoverySpi] Using parameter [mcastPort=30000]
13/04/16 19:01:01.597 [INFO ] [main] [***GridMulticastDiscoverySpi] Using parameter [tcpPort=30001]
13/04/16 19:01:01.597 [INFO ] [main] [***GridMulticastDiscoverySpi] Using parameter [localPortRange=9999]
13/04/16 19:01:01.597 [INFO ] [main] [***GridMulticastDiscoverySpi] Using parameter [beatFreq=3000]
13/04/16 19:01:01.597 [INFO ] [main] [***GridMulticastDiscoverySpi] Using parameter [maxMissedBeats=10]
13/04/16 19:01:01.597 [INFO ] [main] [***GridMulticastDiscoverySpi] Using parameter [leaveAttempts=10]
13/04/16 19:01:01.597 [INFO ] [main] [***GridMulticastDiscoverySpi] Using parameter [localHost=10.***.19.77]
13/04/16 19:01:01.597 [INFO ] [main] [***GridMulticastDiscoverySpi] Using parameter [ttl=8]
13/04/16 19:01:01.597 [INFO ] [main] [***GridMulticastDiscoverySpi] Failed to bind to local TCP port (will try next port within range): 30001
13/04/16 19:01:01.597 [INFO ] [main] [***GridMulticastDiscoverySpi] Failed to bind to local TCP port (will try next port within range): 30002
13/04/16 19:01:01.597 [INFO ] [main] [***GridMulticastDiscoverySpi] Failed to bind to local TCP port (will try next port within range): 30003
13/04/16 19:01:01.597 [INFO ] [main] [***GridMulticastDiscoverySpi] Failed to bind to local TCP port (will try next port within range): 30004
13/04/16 19:01:01.597 [INFO ] [main] [***GridMulticastDiscoverySpi] Failed to bind to local TCP port (will try next port within range): 30005
13/04/16 19:01:01.597 [INFO ] [main] [***GridMulticastDiscoverySpi] Failed to bind to local TCP port (will try next port within range): 30006
13/04/16 19:01:01.597 [INFO ] [main] [***GridMulticastDiscoverySpi] Failed to bind to local TCP port (will try next port within range): 30007
13/04/16 19:01:01.597 [INFO ] [main] [***GridMulticastDiscoverySpi] Failed to bind to local TCP port (will try next port within range): 30008
13/04/16 19:01:01.597 [INFO ] [main] [***GridMulticastDiscoverySpi] Failed to bind to local TCP port (will try next port within range): 30009
13/04/16 19:01:01.597 [INFO ] [main] [***GridMulticastDiscoverySpi] Successfully bound to TCP port: 30010
13/04/16 19:01:01.721 [INFO ] [main] [***GridMulticastDiscoverySpi] Successfully bound to Multicast port: 30000
13/04/16 19:01:01.737 [INFO ] [main] [***GridMulticastDiscoverySpi] Local node: GridMulticastDiscoveryNode [id=b8136fca-19db-4b81-8b91-317fea516aba, state=READY, lastHeartbeat=1366106461721, addr=***calc007/10.***.19.77, tcpPort=30010, startTime=1366106461597]
13/04/16 19:01:01.737 [INFO ] [main] [***GridMulticastDiscoverySpi] Waiting for initial heartbeat timeout (3000 milliseconds)
13/04/16 19:01:02.782 [WARN ] [grid-mcast-disco-tcp-handshake-sender-#37%null] [***GridMulticastDiscoverySpi] Failed to connect to node (did the node stop?) [addr/10.***.19.118, port=30004, error=Connection refused: connect]. Make sure that destination node is alive and has properly configured firewall that allows GridGain incoming traffic (especially on Windows Vista).
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:319)
    at org.gridgain.grid.spi.discovery.multicast.GridMulticastDiscoverySpi$TcpHandshakeSender.body(GridMulticastDiscoverySpi.java:1364)
    at org.gridgain.grid.spi.GridSpiThread.run(GridSpiThread.java:96)
13/04/16 19:01:02.798 [WARN ] [grid-mcast-disco-tcp-handshake-sender-#42%null] [***GridMulticastDiscoverySpi] Failed to connect to node (did the node stop?) [addr/10.***.19.80, port=30007, error=Connection refused: connect]. Make sure that destination node is alive and has properly configured firewall that allows GridGain incoming traffic (especially on Windows Vista).
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:319)
    at org.gridgain.grid.spi.discovery.multicast.GridMulticastDiscoverySpi$TcpHandshakeSender.body(GridMulticastDiscoverySpi.java:1364)
    at org.gridgain.grid.spi.GridSpiThread.run(GridSpiThread.java:96)
```

thank for help.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have another node on "addr/10.***.19.118, port=30004"? If that node is started correctly, please check in your firewall settings. To start off, make sure that software firewall is disabled. Also make sure that hardware firewall allows multicast.